# Clean URL's not working, mod_rewrite module installed

Tags: apache, drupal, mod-rewrite, drupal-6

I just installed a fresh copy of Drupal 6.19 to get to speed on how to write modules. But for some reason the rewrite module isn't working for Drupal.

What I have checked:

- $ `apachectl -M`  >> *it is installed*
- `php_info()` on current server >> *says rewrite is installed also*
- I also [double-checked](http://drupal.org/node/15365) the `.htaccess` file in my Drupal root folder
- UPDATE: checked httpd.conf for `AllowOverride All`

I'm out options here. Looked everywhere but the Drupal settings aren't letting me to enable the settings and their test is simply visiting a site that should work if the rewrite module was there.

My specs:
Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard
Using built-in Apache with PHP5

Thanks!

Comment: If in case you have not tried, You need to enable Clean urls from drupal admin panel. ie. administer->clean urls.

Comment: THAT is what I can't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two more things to check:

1. Verify that your `.htaccess` is readable for your apache processes (Yes, I read that you double checked it, but did that include the file permissions?)
2. [Enable rewrite logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLog) - this might give you some hints on where it fails. Start with a [log level](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLogLevel) of 5 and increase/decrease as needed. (Don't forget to turn it off again later, as it is a huge performance hog ;)

Also, I'd try to simplify the test scenario - start with a simple rewrite directive in a vhost configuration. Once that works, move it to a .htaccess in the top-level of the vhosts document root, then to sub directories (if needed/used).

Comment: Thank you, changing the file permissions worked for some reason. In the start it was: 644 (`-rw-r--r--@`) I changed it using the command `chmod 777` which gave me (`-rwxrwxrwx@`). I then restarded Apache and it worked :) ...strange thing is that when I turned it back to 644 it still worked. Any idea why?

Comment: @WmasterJ: That is strange indeed, and I have no idea why. Unless it is a really strange glitch with the permission settings (which I doubt), the most obvious reason would be that you changed something else that fixed your issue, but just needed the apache restart to take effect!?

Comment: Probably that was the case :<

Answer (score 7):

Last but not least, you must authorize your virtual host or directory to use `.htaccess`.

```
AllowOverride All
```

**Update:**

I can't figure out your exact problem but it's always worth testing that Apache is actually parsing your `.htaccess` file. Make a syntax error on purpose and see if you get a `500 Internal Server Error` message. Also, test `mod_rewrite` with a simple redirection rule that doesn't involve Drupal.

Comment: Yeah, this is the big thing you didn't mention. This line needs to go somewhere in your httpd.conf file.

Comment: +1 because it would definately help someone. For some reason I couldn't solve it still. I made the change in my httpd.conf file (I know i'm editing the correct one) and I then restarted the apache server. It didn't help :(

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that if the install is in a sub-directory that the username is part of the rewriteBase

```
# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
# VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
# For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
# modify the following line:
RewriteBase /~username/drupal**
```

Answer (score 1):

If you running your Drupal installation in a sub-folder like: example.com/drupal, then enable "RewriteBase /" in your .htaccess file, it might help you.

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Did you solved this problem? It is possible, that apache does not read .htaccess file. Try to insert some dummy text stuff inside .htaccess and try to load your page. If you get errors on screen, then it's somewhat other problems related to apache / php config. But if you get no error, then it is apache config (sites-enabled) problems.

Answer (score 1):

A clean url could be something like www.example.com/fisherman instead of www.example.com/data/pages/fisherman.php

Some installations of apache have clean URL functionality out of the box. There are 2 steps that need to be configured correctly for it to work.

```
Enable rewrite module
Allow .htaccess file overrides
```

Both steps require SSH root access to your server. So if you are on shared host this probably won't work for you. Open your terminal:

1. Enable rewrite module

To enable the rewrite module, you can type the following command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Now type

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

to enable the changes. You can check if it’s working by typing

```
sudo apache2ctl –M
```

A list will appear. Look for “rewrite_module”.

http://codeontrack.com/enable-clean-urls-apache/

Answer (score 0):

Look for this Line in your httpd.conf file

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

If commented 
Just uncomment it restart apache server then try enabling in drupal administer Clean URL Section

Comment: Thank you. But if you read my question you will see that I checked both the `apachectl -M` (which shows all active modules) and also php_info() which also shows the currently active modules.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to my .htaccess file and it was solved. My problem was specifically hapening with Rackspace / CentOS image

Options -MultiViews

Answer (score 0):

As Álvaro G. Vicario mentioned, the first thing to do is at the top of the `.htaccess` file add something like `ghfdiddfdjf` which should throw an internal error.  If it doesn't, you know the `.htaccess` file isn't being read.  Mine wasn't, and I found the following fix:

In the `etc/apache2/sites-enabled` folder, there was a file called `default-000`.  It was in this file that I changed `AllowOverride All` in **2** places in the file.