# Help needed with mod_rewrite and htaccess for Drupal

Tags: apache, drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-6

I want to enable .htaccess files on my server in order to use "clean_url" functionality in Drupal.

This is what I've done so far:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
grep mod_rewrite *
```

In phpinfo() results I can see: `mod_rewrite`, so I guess the module is enabled.

I've added a htaccess file with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteBase /path/to/website

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But still it says me my server doesn't provide such functionality. What am I missing ?

Comment: What do you mean by "still it says me my server doesn't provide such functionality"?

Comment: uhm, sorry it was not clear indeed. Drupal inform you if you can turn "clean urls" or not, checking if url rewriting is enabled or not

Comment: What I meant is that it doesn't work.

Comment: Hm..Someone else is [having the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3792809/366234). Are you running the same Drupal version, out of curiosity?

Comment: Yes 6.19  But I don't think it is Drupal. The same website works with htaccess files on another server. I think I miss some server configuration step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to check the configuration for your server or `VirtualHost` to ensure [`AllowOverrides`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is set to `All`. If it isn't, nothing in your .htaccess will be read or acted upon.