# Why don't my clean URL's work in Drupal, even though rewrite_module is present?

Tags: linux, apache, drupal, centos, clean-urls

## Hey guys. I'm asking this question here as a last resort, since I've been trying to solve the issue for almost two days now.

I'm trying to enable clean URL's on my Drupal web application. I have visited **several** public questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792809/clean-urls-not-working-mod-rewrite-module-installed) one, but to no avail. My sincerest apologies if this is thus a repost.

Some (relevant) context:

- The project involves **automatically setting up a VM** using a Vagrant script.
- The VM has **no GUI**.
- Vagrant uses **VirtualBox**.
- Vagrant uses **bento/centos-7.9** as a base box.
- I use **WSL** on my physical device whenever I need a terminal for PS or Linux commands.

I'm setting up a LAMP stack on the VM using the following:

- **CentOS 7.9**, as mentioned up above.
- **Apache 2.4.6**, as in:

`yum -y install httpd`

- **MariaDB 10.5.9**, as in:

`wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup`

`chmod +x mariadb_repo_setup`

`./mariadb_repo_setup`

`yum -y install mariadb-server`

- **PHP 7.4.16**, as in:

`yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`

`yum -y install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm`

`yum-config-manager --enable remi-php74`

`yum -y install php php-mysql`

- I'm storing the extracted contents of Drupal (index.php, update.php,
  core, sites ...) under `/var/www/drupal/`. I have given Apache
  **recursive ownership of that folder** as to not create a hassle having to set up permissions. It's not a production project anyway.
- In the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file, I have only touched the
  **DocumentRoot**, which I set to `DocumentRoot "/var/www/drupal"`. I do **not** want to use **.htaccess**.
- When I run `httpd -M | grep rewrite`, I receive the output **rewrite_module (shared)**. When I run `phpinfo();` on a test page, **mod_rewrite** is present among the loaded modules.

Running the application, everything goes fine, and the following output is produced:

[Drupal warnings top part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRWiS.png)

[Drupal warnings bottom part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czfr6.png)

I'm aware of the other two warnings, but those are a worry for another day. When I continue despite the warnings, Apache loads **index.php** just fine:

[Screenshot of index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEj3p.png)

However, the moment I click **any button**, this happens:

[Screenshot of yet another problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYk0Z.png)

I suspect this is a consequence of the **clean URL's not being enabled**. However, as far as I know, all necessary modules have been installed.

### What I have tried so far:

- In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, trying everything that's suggested [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/configuring-clean-urls/enable-clean-urls).
- In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, setting every **AllowOverride** option to **All**.
- Checking for compability issues.
- Moving the document root around.
- Much more...

Help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance. If you require any more information, I will respond as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hey guys. The issue has been solved.**

Somehow, it suddenly works. I am now able to navigate the website without a **Not Found** error popping up.

I retried a method that didn't work before, but now it does. There was no change in any other variables. I edited `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. Besides already having changed **DocumentRoot** to `/var/www/drupal`, I also added another piece of configuration right under that:

```
<Directory "/var/www/drupal">
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

I obtained this information from [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/configuring-clean-urls/enable-clean-urls).

The **CLEAN URLS** warning is still present though:

[Drupal warnings top part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRWiS.png)

But there seems to be no problem when continuing despite the warnings. In fact, in the application itself, navigating to the errors/warnings section, the **CLEAN URLS** warning isn't even there!